# Auto-click a button only only on first page load

Tags: javascript, html

On my website I've got a button which is clicked automatically by js with the loading of the website.

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
};
```

The thing I don't know how to code is that I want the button only to be auto clicked at the first visit of the page or only once an hour...

Is there a way to do it without using jquery?

Comment: use `Setinterval`.

Comment: jQuery is just library for JS, so yes, you can do it. Save state into local storage and on page load check if state satisfies your requirements and then click on that button

Comment: But `Setinterval` won't help if someone refreshes the page doesn't it?

Comment: @Justinas do you know where I can find how to do that?

Comment: @MaximilianBessrich [JS localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time, but I think something like this will work for you. Let me know if you face any problem with this.

```js
// Initialize an object
let obj = {};

// Trigger when DOM loads
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Get current Date in UNIX
  let currentDate = Date.now();
  // An hour in UNIX
  const hour = 3600000;
  // The date to reclick
  let reclickDate = currentDate + hour;

  // If already clicked
  if (localStorage.getItem('clickData')){
    // Parse the JSON object from localStorage
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clickData'));
    // The Date to Reclick
    reclickDate = Date(parseInt(data.clickTime)+hour);
  }
  // Otherwise click now and set object JSON
  else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    obj.clickTime = Date.now();
    localStorage.setItem('clickData', JSON.stringify(obj));
  }

  // Recursive Function
  checkForClick(currentDate, reclickDate);
});

const checkForClick = (currentDate, reclickDate) => {
  setTimeout(() => {

    // If 1 hour passed
    if (currentDate > reclickDate){
      // Reclick
      document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
      // Set localStorage new data
      obj.clickTime = Date.now();
      localStorage.setItem('clickData', JSON.stringify(obj));
      // Break function
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise recall the function
    checkForClick(currentDate+1000, reclickDate);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately now the button is never clicked even when I open the page on a device I never used before. :(

Comment: Do i have to adjust something or just paste it in the window.onload function?

Comment: @MaximilianBessrich the code checks if there is a cookie set. If there is, it starts calling a function every 1 second which compares time of your cookie and current time. If current time is higher than (cookie time + 1hour) it reclicks the button and re-set a new cookie with current time. If there is no cookie set in page load, it clicks the button and sets a cookie.

Comment: @MaximilianBessrich Do not paste this INSIDE `window.onload`. Paste it stand-alone. It already loads when the DOM of the page is loaded. Be sure to check in `getElementById('')` for the correct button ID. It should work.

Answer (score -2):

Try this below code using document ready function in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").trigger('click'); 
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem detailed in the question. Also the question specifically asks for no jQuery.